# ¿A qué se debe el error "Violación de segmento ('core' generado)

Tags: c, linux, manejo-de-memoria

tengo el siguiente código que estoy realizando para una actividad donde se establece recrear el comando **rm** de linux pero a través de una función, tengo un if dentro del código puesto que la función también debe de ser capaz de captar si se pasa un parámetro dentro de la ejecución (*emulando un rm -y por ejemplo*) y también debe ser capaz de realizar la eliminación del archivo sin parámetros

Al ejecutarlo elimina de manera normal al enviarle un parámetro, sin embargo cuando trato de hacerlo sin este, me da el siguiente error:

**Violación de segmento (`core' generado)**

Adjunto un ejemplo de ejecución
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Separé el código que esta dentro de los if en diferentes archivos y funcionan sin problemas por lo que no se a que se debe este error. Nunca he programado en c hasta ahora y me es un poco confuso puesto que no sé si estoy cometiendo algún error básico sin siquiera saberlo, agradecería su ayuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char cadena[100];
char opcion[] = "s";

if (strcmp(argv[2], "-i") == 0 || strcmp(argv[2], "-y") == 0)
{
    printf("Esta seguro de eliminar el archivo? [s/n]:");
    scanf("%s", cadena);

    if (strcmp(cadena, opcion) == 0)
    {
        if (remove(argv[1]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Eliminado \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error al eliminar archivo \n");
            return (1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Cancelando... \n");
    }
}
else if(strcmp(argv[2], " ") == 0)
{
    if (remove(argv[1]) == 0)
    {
        printf("Eliminado \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error al eliminar \n");
        return (1);
    }
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué parámetros o entrada está recibiendo el programa? Por cierto, `return` no es una función. Los paréntesis son redundantes.

Comment: ./borrar prueba.txt -y (**Este no genera problema**)                                                ./borrar prueba.txt (**Genera problema**)

Comment: La idea es solucionar el problema. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/564622/edit) la pregunta con los parámetros y entradas que generen el problema que indicas por favor.

Comment: `strcmp(argv[2], " ")`, Si no le estas dando un segundo argumento a tu programa, esta linea de código ira a tratar de leer un string a saber ni donde. Pobremente ese lugar sea memoria que no te pertenece, y por eso te sale la violación de segmento. En lugar de hacerlo asi, deberias usar `argc` para ver cuantos argumentos te pasaron. `if (argc == 2) { /*Version donde solo lo borra*/ } else { /*Version que pregunta*/ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error `Segmentation fault` o `Violación de segmento` se produce cuando el programa intenta acceder a memoria que no le pertenece. [Más información](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346849/13419694).

`argv[2]` correspondería a un segundo parámetro, pero el programa intenta acceder a ese parámetro sin importar que no haya recibido un segundo parámetro, derivando en ese error.

`argc` recibe la cantidad de parámetros. Puedes solucionar este inconveniente verificando previamente que la posición a la que intentas acceder se encuentra dentro del rango:

```
if (argc >= 3){
    // Aquí es seguro acceder a las posiciones 0, 1 y 2
}
```

---

Te propongo una mejor solución:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

const char* archivo = "";
int pedirConfirmacion = 0;

void procesarParametro(const char *param){
    if (strcmp(param, "-i") == 0 ||
        strcmp(param, "-y") == 0){
        pedirConfirmacion = 1;
    }
    else {
        archivo = param;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char cadena[100];
    char opcion[] = "s";
    int confirmado = 1;
   
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
         procesarParametro(argv[i]);
    }

    if (pedirConfirmacion) {
        printf("Esta seguro de eliminar el archivo? [s/n]:");
        scanf("%s", cadena);

        if (strcmp(cadena, opcion) == 0) {
            confirmado = 1;
        } else {
            printf("Cancelando... \n");
            confirmado = 0;
        }
    }

    if (confirmado) {
        if (remove(archivo) == 0) {
            printf("Eliminado \n");
        } else {
            printf("Error al eliminar \n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fVJNb8IwDL33V1idJrV8Da4DtgPivjvjkKUBLLVJ5ZRKaPDbuyQEGlo0H9r0Pdd@fg4f7zlvmheUPD9mAha6ylBNDh/RA5TjTxcjlPsOdtJvumKVRSOupK6AHxgNgBE/YK1gCXE8j1BWUIoMaaXkDqlgHJU03HQeRbXCDEpSXGhGX4xYISpSSVsMBqVF098ITOAOEqOEF2Xi4BHEY4xTWJpqcD67HBvdnJPP8WVsPFM0mzv64p4i1wLa/HYmV/WWeYncfAVDmdgDoz0feeUD81GnvoaDOMuEZJvZdLqdt6gqbf/N1vql4ytha3GvLlN3bY7bKQLXDB1uXgvX15yGw2DEJ8ZaRRvcpjf5d1d7dqTB7KXZfbVL4rXZNmixP5ICcwFEjgVKM4DIb/Z8wka/ye177Du4ZXAmzc@vOh55Awx5Z4OVXsmR98NvLJDhDOt74uLS3Veoe8UkFzmTmZpMJvAtQ3W9otOgaNelNjHUZRkShapF4m14rv1u49U30@1Ryr8zrInM2lneut6fg0R1JPlgS3ChPWvmuzRNM/sD) y lo puedes seguir mejorando.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funcionó bajó esa lógica :D